# Does WebApi's async context trickle down to libraries using TaskParallel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I have a .NET library that uses ParallelQueryable and Parallel.ForEach internally to parallelize calculations.

Now, that library is being consumed by a WebApi application. I know that WebApi uses an async context to prevent concurrent access to the current request. My question is, will WebApi's use of this context affect the library's internal parallel computations in any way (for example will continuations all have to be performed on the "GUI" thread?)?

Comment: Using `Parallel.For` on the Web API host is not a good practice - unless the process could take minutes, in which case better use other options. It will steal the same threads used by ASP.NET hence can cause thread starvation.

Comment: @Aliostad: In this case, the WebApi server exists to expose library methods that run potentially long-running computations as a web service. Are you suggesting that the multi-threaded library code run as it's own process?

Comment: not saying that. I am saying that multi-threading on server is not great. You need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make much sense if TPL behaved the way you describe. The whole point of PLINQ and `Parallel.ForEach()` is to execute the code in parallel. And using synchronization context (in ASP.NET or GUI application) to execute these `Task`s would mean they wouldn't execute in parallel. Because of that, PLINQ, `Parallel.ForEach()` and `Task.Run()` don't use the synchronization context.